# SQL Server Bit Array

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, datatable, bitarray

I want to store a bit array in a datatable of mine.

It shouldn't have the same length in every row(it can be for example 001001 which is six chars long or 101000110011 which is 12 chars long).

What is the best way to store such a thing in a SQL Server table?

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointment] (
[ID]                 INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Date]               DATE           NOT NULL,
[StartTime]          TIME (0)       NOT NULL,
[IsFull]             BIT            NULL,
[TimePerAppointment] TIME (0)       NOT NULL,
[Apps]               VARBINARY (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

This is how my table looks like, is varbinary ok?

Comment: Storing an array in a row violates [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Consider normalizing your data.

Comment: @DanGuzman
so what can I do to solve this problem?

I need to store sequence of appointments and know if they are taken or not... any other idea?

Comment: "Appointment" usually involves date and time. Without knowing what you are actually modeling, any suggestions you receive will be guesses - at best.

Comment: If the bits represent appointment slots, those should probably be separate rows in another table but there's not enough info you your question to offer a specific suggestion. Is there a date in the table and the bits represent time slot interval within the day? Add DDL of your existing tables to your question for clarity.

Comment: Is `TimePerAppointment` the uniform duration of each appointment? Is `Date` unique within this table? What looks to be missing is the related table(s) (e.g. Physician and the related PhysicianID in the Appointment table if this model is for doctor appointments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `varbinary` data type perfectly suits your needs.

Please have a look at the official documentation for any further explanation:

[Microsoft - Binary and varbinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[Microsoft - SQL Server Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Does the OP ask for the datatype?

Comment: @Sami - it sounds like an harsh comment, am I wrong? OP stated that he has a datatable where he needs to store some byte arrays. I think I'm just pointing him to some official documentation he could use to explore available choiches.

Comment: I don't know what the OP mean by _What is the best way to store such thing in MS SQL SERVER datatable?_ he could say _best datatype_ instead. That was the meaning of my comment :)

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a datatype that can help me store a sequence of 1s and 0s or true/false or anything like that

Comment: @IsaacTzachChuri Yes there is `BIT` datatype

Comment: @IsaacTzachChuri sometimes existence of record itself is enough to consider a statement as `true`. `False` will be considered when there is no such record.

Comment: A *sequence* of bits, kind of. but it no longer matters I used the varbinary and it works just fine!

Comment: @IsaacTzachChuri in a **normalized** schema it would be a _set_ of records.